# Get cache with yii to image function

Tags: javascript, php, caching, yii

I have this javascript code:

```
function Thumbnail(url) {
    $.each(url, function(key, value){
        $('#thumb_'+key).load(function(){}).attr('src', "http://domain.com/="+encodeURIComponent(value));
    });
}

Thumbnail({<?php echo $id ?>:'<?php echo $domain ?>'});
```

and i have this php code:

```
<img class="thumbnail" id="thumb_<?php echo $id ?>" src="" />
```

how can i save this image to be in folder by chach (**CFileCache**) (i dont need to change the image a lot so the image can be saved in cache for a long time)

Comment: if that's the case just copy image in a directory and give address to that location

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us _what exactly_ it is you want to cache? The image itself? The URL to the image? The thumbnail to a given image? Something entirely different?

Comment: i dont want to save all the images in a folder, just the images that generate, so by cache i want to be able to save those images in a folder (the thumb/image itself)